# Find the number of elements in each factorgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules

[image]

(a) and (c) are 2 and 3 and I don't think I have a problem with those.

However for (b) I get 11 cosets but they are not disjoint. According to theory there should only be 6. So what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Consider [b]. The element $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}/12$ has order $12/\gcd(8,12) = 3$: indeed we have $8+8+8 = 24 \equiv 0 \mod 12$. Thus the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/12)/\langle 8 \rangle$ is $12/3 = 4$. Explicitly, the cosets are $\langle 8 \rangle = \{0,8,4\}$, $1+\langle 8 \rangle = \{1,9,5\}$, $2+\langle 8\rangle = \{2,10,6\}$ and $3+\langle 8 \rangle = \{3,11,7\}$.

More generally, the order of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m$ is $m/\gcd(n,m)$ and so the order of the factor group $(\mathbb{Z}/m)/\langle n \rangle$ is $m/(m/\gcd(n,m)) = \gcd(n,m)$.

Answer (score 1):

The image of $8\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ is the same as the image of $\langle 8,12\rangle=\gcd(8,12)\mathbb Z=4\mathbb Z$.

This same idea works for all items.

The precise idea hint at above is to consider the canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$. Then $\pi^{-1}(\langle 8\rangle)=\gcd(8,12)\mathbb Z=4\mathbb Z$ and so $\dfrac{\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z}{\langle 8\rangle} \cong \dfrac{\mathbb Z}{4\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: So you are implying that the answer for (b) is 4? And that it is because $8\mathbb{Z}$ mod 12 is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $4\mathbb{Z}$ has 3 elements mod 12 though.

Comment: @15yyyyy, you're right, but you want the index of $4\mathbb Z \bmod 12$, which is $12/3=4$, which is the same as the index of $4\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Z$.